# Can't load XML from Resource/Drawable/

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've saved my Xml in Resource/Drawable/ . I put it here cause is the only place where it can stay without any error.

Any way this is the exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/sds".

How can I find the path?

Here is my code:

```
String conditionName = "";
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("@drawable/LightConditions.xml");                
foreach (XElement item in xml.Root.Elements("Condizione"))
{
    if (item.Element("EV").Value == EV)
    {
        conditionName = item.Parent.Element("Nome").Value;
        break;
    }
    //do something
}
```

Comment: /resource/drawable is not for arbitrary XML files. It is for drawables only. Add your XML to Assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to place that `.xml` in the `Assets` folder and flag the build action as an `AndroidAsset`.

Then you can use the `AssetManager` to access it via a `Stream`:

```
string conditionName = "";
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(this.Assets.Open("LightConditions.xml")))
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(sr);
    foreach (XElement item in xml.Root.Elements("Condizione"))
    {
        if (condizione.Element("EV").Value == EV)
        {
            conditionName = item.Parent.Element("Nome").Value;
            break;
        }
        //do something
    }
}
```

Consult the `Xamarin.Android` guide on [Assets](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/)